# Mule 4 /DW 2.0 how do I upsert this JSON on the basis of 'Title'?

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, dataweave, mulesoft

I have a JSON as follows:

```
[{
        "Number": "66667",
        "Date": "2020-08-29 16:40:32.0",
        "Account Number":  {"externalId":1,"account": 122},
        "Title": "ABC",
        "Auto Reversing": "",
        "Debit": 20,
        "Credit": 0
    },
    {
        "Number": "66667",
        "Date": "2020-08-29 16:40:32.0",
        "Account Number":  {"externalId":1,"account": 122},
        "Title": "ABC",
        "Auto Reversing": "",
        "Debit": 10,
        "Credit": 0
    },
    {
        "Number": "66667",
        "Date": "2020-08-29 16:40:32.0",
        "Account Number":  {"externalId":1,"account": 122},
        "Title": "ABC",
        "Auto Reversing": "",
        "Debit": 0,
        "Credit": 30
    },
    {
        "Number": "66667",
        "Date": "2020-08-29 16:40:32.0",
        "Account Number":  {"externalId":1,"account": 3144},
        "Title": "DEF",
        "Auto Reversing": "",
        "Debit": 10,
        "Credit": 0
    },
    {
        "Number": "66667",
        "Date": "2020-08-29 16:40:32.0",
        "Account Number":  {"externalId":1,"account": 3144},
        "Title": "DEF",
        "Auto Reversing": "",
        "Debit": 0,
        "Credit": 10
    }
]
```

I have to upload this data onto netsuite, as such, there should only be records created in netsuite based on the distict titles in the 'Title' field (`ABC` and `DEF` here).

Each entry for the same title should keep updating the records, for example, for each entry of title `ABC`, there should only be 1 record in netsuite with all the values updated.

I've tried using `groupby`, however, upserting the groupby object dynamically is giving me issues. Here is the output after groupby.

```
{
  "DEF": [
    {
      "Number": "66667",
      "Date": "2020-08-29 16:40:32.0",
      "Account Number": {
        "externalId": 1,
        "account": 3144
      },
      "Title": "DEF",
      "Auto Reversing": "",
      "Debit": 0,
      "Credit": 10
    },
    {
      "Number": "66667",
      "Date": "2020-08-29 16:40:32.0",
      "Account Number": {
        "externalId": 1,
        "account": 3144
      },
      "Title": "DEF",
      "Debit": 0,
      "Credit": 10
    }
  ],
  "ABC": [
    {
      "Number": "66667",
      "Date": "2020-08-29 16:40:32.0",
      "Account Number": {
        "externalId": 1,
        "account": 3144
      },
      "Title": "ABC",
      "Debit": 20,
      "Credit": 0
    },
    {
      "JE Number": "66667",
      "JE Date": "2020-08-29 16:40:32.0",
      "Account Number": {
        "externalId": 1,
        "account": 3144
      },
      "Journal Entry Title": "ABC",
      "Debit": 10,
      "Credit": 0
    },
    {
      "JE Number": "66667",
      "JE Date": "2020-08-29 16:40:32.0",
      "Account Number": {
        "externalId": 1,
        "account": 3144
      },
      "Journal Entry Title": "ABC",
      "Debit": 0,
      "Credit": 30
    }
  ]
}
```

I have no clue on how do I further proceed with this.

Comment: What is the expected output and what are exactly the problems/errors you are having?

Answer (score 3):

Let me start by saying your question is unclear.  I will latch on this for my answer below: 
"In total, there should only be 2 records generated, one with title ABC and the other with DEF."

I did make use of `dw::core::Objects::mergeWith` function, you can find the documentation here: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/dw-objects-functions-mergewith

Try this: `payload distinctBy $.Title`

Edit:
Now that you further clarified the question, I can tell you I have no clue how to use the netsuite connector but I do know DW and I can incrementally update the objects with the same `Title` thus giving me the updated result.

Try this code instead:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/dw
var data = [{
        "Number": "66667",
        "Date": "2020-08-29 16:40:32.0",
        "Account Number":  {"externalId":1,"account": 122},
        "Title": "ABC",
        "Auto Reversing": "",
        "Debit": 20,
        "Credit": 0
    },
    {
        "Number": "66667",
        "Date": "2020-08-29 16:40:32.0",
        "Account Number":  {"externalId":1,"account": 122},
        "Title": "ABC",
        "Auto Reversing": "",
        "Debit": 10,
        "Credit": 0
    },
    {
        "Number": "66667",
        "Date": "2020-08-29 16:40:32.0",
        "Account Number":  {"externalId":1,"account": 122},
        "Title": "ABC",
        "Auto Reversing": "",
        "Debit": 0,
        "Credit": 30
    },
    {
        "Number": "66667",
        "Date": "2020-08-29 16:40:32.0",
        "Account Number":  {"externalId":1,"account": 3144},
        "Title": "DEF",
        "Auto Reversing": "",
        "Debit": 10,
        "Credit": 0
    },
    {
        "Number": "66667",
        "Date": "2020-08-29 16:40:32.0",
        "Account Number":  {"externalId":1,"account": 3144},
        "Title": "DEF",
        "Auto Reversing": "",
        "Debit": 0,
        "Credit": 10
    }
]
---
// Group the data by Title
data groupBy $.Title
// Iterate over the object
mapObject {
    ($$): (
        // Iterate over the array in the values and mergeWith the sequence 
        // of objects with the same title
        // NOTE: the values to the right take precedence when using mergeWith.
        $ reduce (e, acc={}) -> acc dw::core::Objects::mergeWith e
    )
}
// Restore the array with the updated objects
pluck $
```